# Wordpress Customize

Tags: javascript, wordpress, compiler-errors

I've searched and not found an answer to why my .js file keeps giving me an error wp not defined in the wp.customize function. 
I've enqueued the script like this

```
    function ws_customizer_live_preview(){ wp_enqueue_script( 'ws-themecustomizer', get_template_directory_uri() .'/library/js/theme-customizer.js', array( 'jquery','customize-preview' ), true ); } add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'ws_customizer_live_preview' );
```

This was basically copied from WP Docs. The javascript is

```
    (function( $ ) {
"use strict";

wp.customize( 'ws_display_header', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( to ) {
        false === to ? $( '.header' ).hide() : $( '.header' ).show();
    } );
});
wp.customize( 'ws_footer_copyright_text', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( to ) {
        $( 'span#copyright-message' ).text( to );
    });
}); })(jQuery);
```

I need to know why the wp.customize in the js is giving me wp not defined error.
Thank you

Comment: Without knowing about wordpress, all I can tell you is that it expects another library to be loaded before this one, that will load "wp" so that this module can use it.

Have a look at where you include javascript and put this at the bottom.